# Есть кнопка, и нужно при нажатии добавить еще 1 кнопку. Если еще раз нажать, тогда еще раз добавить, и т.д

Tags: c#, winforms, события

Здраствуйте. Помогите с добавлением кнопок. Это нужно для дальнейшей работы.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я знаю, что добавить - Button but = new Button(); ....
                       Controls.Add(but);
Отступ, вот, что нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int offsetY = 5;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int index = 1;
foreach(Button oldB in Controls.OfType<Button>()) 
{
  x = oldB.Location.X;
  y = Math.Max(y, oldB.Location.Y + oldB.Height);
  index++;
}

Button b = new Button();
b.Location = new Point(x, y + offsetY);
b.Text = "Button " + index.ToString();
Controls.Add(b);
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли.

Comment: @IODAYSIProJect Пожалуйста. Успехов!